# Optimally placing rectangles with obstacles

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, computational-geometry, integer-programming

I am struggling with a fairly simple and natural geometric optimization problem, but I have not been able to find an obvious canonical method for solving it:

I am given a collection of $m$ axis-aligned rectangles in the unit square, and my goal is to find the optimal positions of a set of $k$ distinct axis-aligned rectangles *with given dimensions* such that none of the $m+k$ rectangles intersect, and the sum of distances between the centers of the $k$ rectangles are minimized.  Distances between rectangles are measured with respect to the length of the shortest $L_1$ path that does not intersect another rectangle (so it's often larger than standard $L_1$ distance).

Is there a field of optimization or computational geometry that would deal with this?  I don't even see an obvious way to formulate it as a mixed integer linear program, due to the presence of shortest paths.

Comment: Are your rectangle sides aligned with the surrounding unit square, or are they oriented arbitrarily?

Comment: Why not place $k$ tiny squares in some little gap. The sum of the distances between those rectangles can be as small as desired. I must not understand the problem correctly...

Comment: Thanks @JosephO'Rourke, I'll clarify.  Everything is axis-aligned, but the $k$ rectangles have given dimensions.

Comment: This is close to what is known as the *labeling problem*. Here is a chapter by K.Kakoulis & I.Tollis that might help: [PDF download](https://cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/chapters/labeling.pdf). Most versions are NP-hard.

Comment: maybe not unrelated: the problem of "Squaring the Square", which is partitioning a square into a set of unequal squares. There is a [chapter in Bollobas book "Modern Graph Theory"](https://books.google.de/books?id=SbZKSZ-1qrwC&pg=PA46&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false). What is interesting, is the relation to electrical networks, which *may* be worth considering in your problem.